# Text Area content not updating in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox-addon

I have created a HTML document with following code..

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="main">
Hi this is sample content
</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

**My problem is that I am not able to update the content of the textarea using javascript.**
I am using Firefox 3.6 on Ubuntu

Now I am using a Firefox addon for this and I have added this code to the overlay.js file

```
window.content.document.getElementById("main").innerHTML += "some content";
```

As none of the code is working and i need to change the content of the textarea in any possible way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to look at the Error Console? My guess is that the browser didn't find the textarea because the script is above it. Try putting the script below the textarea declaration or put the code in a function and call it on body onload event.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My Page</title>
<script>
function updateTextarea(id, value){
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += value;
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="updateTextarea('main', 'some content')">
<textarea id="main">
Hi this is sample content
</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've tried your code here and it gives me a error which tells that main is null.

Comment: @Chaitnya `null.innerHTML += "some content";` Doesn't cause an error? :P

Comment: Do you have anything else using id=main?

Comment: Refused to execute a JavaScript script. Source code of script found within request.

Getting this error on executing this code

Answer (score 1):

Replace Line in Script tag
document.getElementById("main").innerHTML += "some content";
With
document.getElementById('main').value += "Some text";

Answer (score 0):

Your referencing "main" before it loads. Gotta put the getElementById in an onload function, or move your script to below the textarea tag.

EDIT: I don't understand the problem your having. As long as the script isn't run before the textarea is defined it works fine. Certainly not something that should need a browser plugin.

This works fine in my Firefox...

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <textarea id="main">This is initial content... </textarea>
    <script>
      document.getElementById("main").innerHTML += "more content.";
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```